# Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat

Tags: react-native

Metro has encountered an error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/.../Development/swapshop/Mobile-App/my-app/node_modules/prop-types/node_modules': node:fs (2542:7)

Not quite sure why I am getting this error, this shows up on my ios simulator every time a run the app. It didnt show up before, but I deleted node-modules and ran npm install in attempt to debug another issue, but now I am recieving this issue.

this is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start --dev-client",
        "android": "expo run:android",
        "ios": "expo run:ios",
        "web": "expo start --web"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.3",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
        "add": "^2.0.6",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "expo": "~48.0.15",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.8",
        "react-native-auth0": "^2.17.2",
        "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.2",
        "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.2.42",
        "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^2.0.3",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-paper": "^5.8.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.3",
        "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
        "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^4.0.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-wagmi-charts": "^2.3.0",
        "stacktrace-parser": "^0.1.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Ive tried deleting my node modules and npm installing again. Ive cleared npm cache as well as running npx react-native start --reset-cache

Nothing seems to be working and it results in the same error.

Comment: heave you tried running with --reset-cache flag after reinstalling metro?